# Cannot find type System.Windows.DependencyObject in module WindowsBase.dll

Tags: c#, xaml, azure-ad-msal, winui-3

I'm using WinUI 3. I used the Project Reunion 0.5 (Blank App WinUI 3 in Desktop). I removed the x86 and arm64 architecture. As soon as I add the `Microsoft.Identity.Client` nuget package, I have this error :  `Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Cannot find type System.Windows.DependencyObject in module WindowsBase.dll`.

Does anyone have the solution of this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the [Microsoft Authentication Library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) does not currently support WinUI 3. See [this feature request](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/2673) for tracking its development.

**Update:**

Upgrading to WinAppSDK 1.0 or newer fixes this issue, as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5143#issuecomment-923121463).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes it seams that it's not currently supported. To fix this, I'm using the 4.27.1 version and it's works.

Comment: @droyer I don't know how you figured out that 4.27.1 works but you are my hero